# Put 1 of 3 batteries the "wrong way" to prevent accidental turning on?

Tags: batteries, protection, reverse-polarity

My headlamp accidentally turns on inside my backpack. If it used two batteries, I would put one the "wrong way" to prevent it from coming on. However, my lamp uses THREE AAA-type batteries. Can I invert one to get the same effect?

Comment: Or just take one out? Or put a piece of non-conductive material (plastic/paper/rubber) between the battery and contact?

Comment: NEVER put a battery backwards. That's just asking for trouble. Just take the batteries (or at least one) out. Don't be stupid.

Comment: Putting a battery in backwards does not mean it won't drain if it turns on, battery have internal resistance that heats up and still conducts electrons even if backwards. In the two battery situation this effect is probably minimal because the voltages are closely matched, in a three battery device, this won't work. It would be interesting to use a multimeter and see how much current they conduct. Eventually you'd kill a battery and it would probably corrode.

Answer (score 7):

If you have two batteries and they have precisely the same voltage then placing one backwards will effectively cancel out the voltages and no current will flow.

However, batteries aren't like that. The slightest difference in voltages mean that current will flow. Not as much as normal, but some will still flow. And that means, if the lamp is turned on, dead batteries - just not as fast.

Introduce a big imbalance, which is what you do with 3 batteries (2:1 voltage ratio) you end up with considerably more current flowing round your circuit, which means flatter batteries quicker.

Add to that the fact that you have current flowing *backwards* through one battery (even with just 2 batteries) and you are really asking for trouble.

So all in all turning one battery around is a ReallyBadIdea™ and should be avoided. Instead remove one battery entirely, or insert an insulating material between two batteries or between a battery and its contact.

Alternatively fix the switch so it doesn't keep turning on.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it is *possible* that reversing one battery would cause the low voltage lockout (if there actually is one) to actuate and not turn on, this solution is fraught with risk. Reversing two batteries accidentally could damage the unit. Also a headlamp that's badly designed so the power switch can be accidentally pressed is less likely to have protection circuits (the main purpose would be to protect a possible rechargeable battery or possibly the circuit).

If you are willing to open the battery case anyway, you can just take the cells out and put them in a plastic holder for transport. I use ones like this one:

[image: http://www.oempromo.com/upload/Prod_406/AA-Battery-Case_16621822.jpg]

Or, devise some mechanical shield for the power switch.

Answer (score 1):

Turning one of three backwards will not prevent it from being turned on. I had batteries fail and drain to the point of reversal, yet could still turn the flashlight on. It was dimmer, but still visible. Eventually the reversed battery will leak, or worse explode (unlikely for alkaline, but possible).

The simplest option is adding a plastic or cardboard tab between the battery and the terminal in the battery holder, like they do in any number of products or toys that ship with batteries. You break the connection, so the switch does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't play around with reversing the battery polarity just to keep the device form turning on. You could ruin the batteries (or at least drain them) and risk potentially damaging your device. Your "ideal" options:

1) Take all the batteries out and rubber-band them together in a cluster to prevent losing any.

2) Tape/affix your device's "on" switch to the "off" position to prevent it from turning on unexpectedly.

3) Stick a piece of nonconducting material (tape? cloth? depends on what you have on hand. electrical tape would be easy) between any two of the batteries and that should keep them from conducting in a circuit.

The easiest thing to do of these is the third since it doesn't involve opening the battery compartment every time you want to use the device.